# Aggregate over two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I'm new to python and pandas and maybe i'm missing something. I have many columns in a dataframe with two important columns in particular: *Weight* and *Volume*. I want to create many clusters with the rows from the dataframe, with conditions:

- No cluster accumulate (summing) above 30000 Kg in weight.
- No cluster accumulate (summing) above 30 M^3 in volume.
- The cluster are as large as possible but bellow limits expressed in first two points.
- The resulting cluster for each row is annotated in a "cluster" column in the same dataframe.

The algorithm is implemented in a procedural style, with nested loops. I'm reading about rolling and expanding functions in pandas, but i don't find a pandoric way (without loops?) to do that. Is there a way?

[Here](https://github.com/gabomgp/sample_code_stackoveflow_question/blob/master/SampleCode.ipynb) is some code to help explaining me.

Comment: why don't you add an example of what you're starting with and what you'd like the output to be

Comment: what is a cluster?

Comment: I'll add some code, after i simplify and extract the important part. And we use the word "cluster" to identify a group of rows that accumulate maximum weight and volume, but bellow the expressed limits. That after filtering the rows that are possible to match with the current row.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird: the sample code is submitted. I hope the code help to clear the question.